# DataGridView select row and edit in another form

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

When I double clicked on DataGridView cell (row) I need to select and edit this row in a new form. I use MySql and C#.net. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Catch `CellBeginEdit` event, verify that cell is in the right column, and open the new form.